# I Can Understand This Error Someone Help Please

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

```
  if(target.roles.cache.has('937250064894664734')){
                   ^
```

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'cache')
at Object.execute (C:\Users\mihri\OneDrive\Desktop\Adomis\Bot\Adomis-Bot\commands\mute.js:6:24)
at Client. (C:\Users\mihri\OneDrive\Desktop\Adomis\Bot\Adomis-Bot\main.js:57:37)
at Client.emit (node:events:390:28)
at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\mihri\OneDrive\Desktop\Adomis\Bot\Adomis-Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:34:18)
at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\mihri\OneDrive\Desktop\Adomis\Bot\Adomis-Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\mihri\OneDrive\Desktop\Adomis\Bot\Adomis-Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:351:31)
at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\mihri\OneDrive\Desktop\Adomis\Bot\Adomis-Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\mihri\OneDrive\Desktop\Adomis\Bot\Adomis-Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\mihri\OneDrive\Desktop\Adomis\Bot\Adomis-Bot\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:199:18)
at WebSocket.emit (node:events:390:28)

The Error

module.exports ={
name: 'mute',
description: 'Mute Command',
execute(message, args){
const target = message.mentions.users.first();
if(target.roles.cache.has('937250064894664734')){
if(target){
let mainRole = message.guild.cache.find(role => role.name === 'member')
let mutedRole = message.guild.cache.find(role => role.name === 'muted')

```
        let memberTarget = message.guild.members.cache.get(target.id);
        memberTarget.roles.remove(mainRole.id)
        memberTarget.roles.add(mutedRole)

        message.channel.send("Kullanici Susturulmustur!")
    }

    else{
        message.channel.send("Kullanici Bulunamamistir!")
    }
   }

   else{
       message.channel.send("Bu Komutu Kullanmak Icin Yetkin Yoktur!")
   }
}
```

}

The Code

Answer (score 0):

It means that whether target.roles or target itself is undefined. You should validate it first such as:

```
 if (target && target.roles && target.roles.cache && target.roles.cache.has('937250064894664734')) {
   ....
 }
```

Anyway, you can just

```
 if (target?.roles?.cache?.has('...')) {
  ...
 }
```

Comment: Optional chaining is not exclusive to TypeScript